# Android TextView - sendAfterTextChanged

Tags: java, android, textview

Is it possible to override `sendAfterTextChanged(Editable text)` in TextView? I need to skip it in certain situations because it has really long execution time  in my app.

Comment: Here is a link to your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to override `sendAfterTextChanged(Editable text)` in TextView?

Short answer: No. This method is package private. You can't override it from your (different) package.

Long answer: There exists a bug in Dalvik which apparently allowed this but was fixed in ART (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23094051/2367849)).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Unfortunatelly I can't rely on a bug.