# Android app falling after start

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, that when I run my android app it falls immediately. It's weird, because I don't have any error in my console. Here is my console log from debugging:

```
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1424)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/cz.sudoman281.kubirovacikalkulacka-1/lib/arm64
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is cz.sudoman281.kubirovacikalkulacka, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/cz.sudoman281.kubirovacikalkulacka-1/lib/arm64
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 28.661ms
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Do you any large size images in Your application? please upload your gradle file and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @AjayJayendran no I don't. Gradle: http://pastebin.com/esCEsXpR, manifest: http://pastebin.com/ZEk0TaE6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add the following line in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
...
android:largeHeap="true"
...
/>
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

i'd check the method where you are calling the drawable resource, the log says something about an override tag, it could be weel code but crash because the way you implemented is not correct,

its dificult to say something without the source code, but check it.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

> I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is
>   cz.sudoman281.kubirovacikalkulacka, real application class is null.

I would try to disable the instantRun from Gradle studio settings, clean the project and see if it helps.

[Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)

Comment: thanks for reply, but still not working :( Now I am getting this: W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/cz.sudoman281.kubirovacikalkulacka-1/lib/arm64
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', .....

Comment: Than this is the next problem on the list. I think it will faster if you can share a minimal example with the failure, otherwise you can read this post and try to figure something out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005656/android-method-with-default-package-visibility-overriding-shouldnt-work-but

Comment: You can download my whole project here: https://mega.nz/#!t1QzWRxD!qDs6GrcOiKJ05cESG1DlLB00cduOEFhrWBZmCHsVsK8

Comment: I have check it and the project setup looks fine and it works in my studio. I though found a npe and had to move the FloatingActionButton addButton = (FloatingActionButton) thisView.findViewById(R.id.add); and addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  into the onCreateView from the Set fragment. If you still get some more problems you can try some Invalidate cache / Restart or maybe update the android studio.