# Navigating to the another actvity app getting crash in android

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-volley

I'm new to Android and making the Login Page for the SudentApplication.

Have 3 activities in application,FrontPage LoginActivity and PageLogActivity.
In FrongPage just gave a login symbol when user clicks on that symbol it will navigate to next activity call "LoginActvity", Here User giving UserName and Password and that connecting to the Php server there if both the username and password matches the response will come as "true".and also given remember to the user.
That Code is Like this: LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher, 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private CheckBox rem_userpass;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private EditText etUserNmae,etPassword;
private Button btLogin;

String userName;
String password;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "prefs";
private static  final String KEY_REMEMBER = "remember";
private static final  String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
private  static final  String KEY_PASS = "password";

String url = "https://domainname.com/folderName/login";

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    etUserNmae = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
    rem_userpass = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    btLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_REMEMBER,false)){
        rem_userpass.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        rem_userpass.setChecked(false);
    }


    etUserNmae.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME,""));
    etPassword.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PASS,""));

    etUserNmae.addTextChangedListener(LoginActivity.this);
    etPassword.addTextChangedListener(LoginActivity.this);
    rem_userpass.setOnCheckedChangeListener(LoginActivity.this);

    btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int idi = view.getId();
            switch (idi) {
                case R.id.btlogin:
                    doing();
                    break;

            }
        }

        private void doing() {
             userName = etUserNmae.getText().toString();
             password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
                etUserNmae.setError("Please enter UserName");
                etPassword.setError("Please enter password");
                return;
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                etPassword.setError("Please enter password");
                return;
            }else {
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response);
                        if (response.contains("true")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PageLogActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while reading data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("username", etUserNmae.getText().toString());
                        params.put("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
                        return params;
                    }
                };
           MySingleton.getmInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    managePrefs();

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
    managePrefs();
}

 private void managePrefs(){
     if(rem_userpass.isChecked()) {
         editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, etUserNmae.getText().toString().trim());
         editor.putString(KEY_PASS, etPassword.getText().toString().trim());
         editor.putBoolean(KEY_REMEMBER, true);
         editor.apply();
     }else {
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_REMEMBER, false);
         editor.remove(KEY_USERNAME);
         editor.remove(KEY_PASS);
         editor.apply();
     }
     }
 }
```

Geeting the response but when click Login button ut's getting the msg as a Unfrochunatly app as closed.
It's not going to the NextACtivity.

And MYSingleTon class is like this:

```
public class MySingleton {

private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;


private MySingleton(Context context){
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    //for loadig Image....

    mImageLoader  = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

        private final LruCache<String,Bitmap>
           cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

          cache.put(url,bitmap);
        }
    });
}

public  static synchronized MySingleton getmInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance == null){

        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);

    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){

    if (mRequestQueue == null){

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req){
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getmImageLoader(){
    return mImageLoader;
}}
```

Comment: what does the logcat say

Comment: Can you please post error log cat as well

Comment: @mehulmpt .OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11833468 - byte allocation with 4194208 free bytes and 8MB until OOM

Comment: in that case did you try adding this android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , android:largeHeap="true" to your manifest file ?

Comment: @MRX in which activity i need to add those 2 lines

Comment: Are you loading an image that is of large size. Check it out and if thats true scale your image before using it in imageview

Comment: @AnushaB : No in your application tag in manifest file add these 2 line

Comment: @MRX no just am using 2TextView for username and password, and given logic to remember.

Comment: What about your  mImageLoader in Mysingleton class ? isn't that loading some image

Comment: @mehulmpt still it's not working.

Comment: @MRX ya and I just used that code for requesting Volley.

Comment: remove the image loader code and try running it and see if that remove your error

Comment: @MRX if I remove that line no action will taking place.MySingleton.getmInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);  replace of this line which line i need to add.

Comment: Try this by add line `RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();`  above `StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest....`.

Comment: @Nitin Patel getting like this Verbose in Logcat 06-27 12:29:58.496 19443-19443/com.frocerie.demoalqalam D/FeatureProxyBase: FeatureProxyBase class constructor
06-27 12:29:58.496 19443-19443/com.frocerie.demoalqalam D/MultiWindow: MultiWindowProxy constructor.

Comment: One more thing instead of getApplicationContext write(use)  `LoginActivity.this` in LoginActivity for api code.

Comment: Change `RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).getRequestQ‌​ueue();` and

Comment: MySingleton.getmInstance(LoginActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

Comment: @Nithin Patel When click button no action is going. 06-27 12:37:00.733 23499-23499/com.frocerie.demoalqalam D/skia: jpeg_decoder finish successfully, L:1843!!!
06-27 12:37:00.760 23499-23515/com.frocerie.demoalqalam I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 55(2112B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 84MB/84MB, paused 7.925ms total 23.614ms

Comment: Please remove imageLoader coding if you have.

Comment: @Nithin Patel If I remove MySingleton class it's showing error.

Comment: You don' t have to delete whole MySingleton Class. I will give you whole class by link. just after you got , just replace whole coding except first line which is your package. Give you link

Comment: @Nithin Patel Thank You, I will check it and let you know.

Comment: @AnushaB ok. if you still find issue let me know.

Comment: @Nithi Patel Still it's not working when I add  MySingleton.getInstance(LoginActivty.this).getRequestQueue(); this line no action is taking place, But, when i add MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest); Getting the Volley error "Error while reading data".

Comment: @Nithin Patel onResponse() is not at all working my application, am not getting the response as "true".

Comment: You have to change getApplicationContext to `LoginActivty.this` even for addToRequestQueue().

Comment: And for volley error make sure and check URL is proper, and parameters key like username etc. are exact and same as using at server side.

Comment: @Nithin Patel  MySingleton.getInstance(LoginActivty.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest); i wrie that line like this, when i click loginButton im getting LogCat as:06-27 13:20:17.203 24605-24700/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-27 13:20:17.443 24605-24700/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7fb0a1d600,w=720,h=1280)
06-27 13:20:17.450 24605-24700/com.frocerie.audioapplication W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 6942

Comment: Is this error ? or select error in android monitor and paste here.

Comment: going for lunch, so ping if you still face issue.

Comment: @Nithin Patel yes it's same as the name used in server side but still getting "Error while reading data".

Comment: @Nithin Patel No error in logCat, Just when press login button getting Tost as "Error while reading data".

Comment: Did you give **Internet permission** in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Nithin Patel ya I given Internet permission also.

Comment: Good then I will give you volley error code and change and we will find what is error.

Comment: @Nithin Patel 06-27 15:01:42.379 23880-23900/com.frocerie.audioapplication E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Comment: @Nithin Patel 06-27 15:03:45.040 23880-23880/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/FeatureProxyBase: getService(), serviceName = multiwindow_service_v1 getting Sever Error

Comment: So, its server error. right?

Comment: @Nithin Patel yes, how to resolve it??

Comment: can any one please reply....I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @AnushaB Comment the what response code just I have given and add this:   `Log.e("Volley Error....", error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  means replace it. So, we can find it.

Comment: @Nithin Patel how I get log cat, for your code.

Comment: In androidMonitor Verbose there will be line like ::Volley Error.... find it.

Comment: @Nithin Patel when I press Login button I'm not getting any Toast message.

Comment: Do u know how to debug

Comment: @Nithin Patel 06-27 15:34:03.832 27284-27284/com.frocerie.audioapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-27 15:34:04.041 27284-27360/com.frocerie.audioapplication E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Comment: @Nithin Patel, I don't know can you please guide me.

Comment: Try this..https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410489/7806873

Comment: Now its better to move chat in another.

Comment: Good. You have solved that?

Comment: @Nithin Patel, there I didn't  the solution for my problem.

Comment: Now what is error?

Comment: @Nithin Patel In that link I didn't get the solution,06-27 16:03:32.097 27284-27284/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/FeatureProxyBase: FeatureProxyBase class constructor
06-27 16:03:32.101 27284-27284/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/MultiWindow: MultiWindowProxy constructor.
06-27 16:03:32.101 27284-27284/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/FeatureProxyBase: getService(), serviceName = multiwindow_service_v1
06-27 16:03:32.244 27284-27360/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7fb0a1d600,w=720,h=1280)

Comment: Do you add that line AndroidManifest?

Comment: @Nithin Patel Yes I add but still, it's not going to next activity.

Comment: Now error is toast or not?

Comment: @Nithin Patel, No Nothing is happening.

Comment: Now you have to put debug points at first line of VolleyError and onResponse and have to debug and evaluate(check) value.

Comment: @Nithin Patel Ya I gave breakpoint and started debug process In Verbose I get this 3 lines.                                                                         06-27 16:24:28.666 19347-19347/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/FeatureProxyBase: FeatureProxyBase class constructor
06-27 16:24:28.666 19347-19347/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/MultiWindow: MultiWindowProxy constructor.
06-27 16:24:28.666 19347-19347/com.frocerie.audioapplication D/FeatureProxyBase: getService(), serviceName = multiwindow_service_v1

Comment: @Nithin Patel and when I check Debug, Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8704', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8704', transport: 'socket'
Like this lines i'm getting.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31315769/7806873 and let me know.

Comment: Did you solve that?

Comment: Just last suggestion to delete this question so, you will not get negative rating any more. Enjoy coding...

Comment: @Nithin Patel, I changed added this line MySingleton.getInstance(LoginActivty.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

Comment: @Nithin Patel it's going to next Activity.

Comment: @Nithin Patel, but the thing is  I removed else part where I'm going to check username and password is empty or not.if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
etUserNmae.setError("Please enter UserName");
 etPassword.setError("Please enter password");return;
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

                    etPassword.setError("Please enter password");
                    return;}//else// {
Directly i written   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new  { this code ... it's is gud coding or what??

Comment: Better make one function (in that add all else part's coding) and just only call that function from else. I can this is good.

Comment: Please delete this question as professional member of stackoverflow!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148108/discussion-between-anusha-b-and-nitin-patel).