# Android: Package installer keeps stopping

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android development I hope somebody can help me.

I created an app (minimum Android 4.4) using Android Studio which successfully runs on the Android Studio Emulator, MEmu Emulator and Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime mobile phone.

The problem is it shows an error `Package installer keeps stopping` if I try to install it to Samsung Galaxy S7 edge (Android 7) and some local phone (Android 4.4).

The is no error on the Android Studio. I also tried building the `.apk` again but there's no luck.

This is the logcat

```
android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Any error showing on the logcat?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question.

Comment: Firstly I am not a Ma'am :) Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005656/android-method-with-default-package-visibility-overriding-shouldnt-work-but

Comment: I'm so sorry :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, but in my case after generating signed APK, it could be installed in some phones and not in others. So, my mistake was a logo size was 2400x2400 (too big). I reduced the size (to under 600 px) and now it works on every phone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as Md.Abdul Halim Rafi. Details below.

The dimensions on my custom icon were too large (>1600x1600). I reduced the same image to < 500x500 using online image reducer (Google around for one). Redid the build for the debug apk and installed it. I can now install, run, and uninstall the app again.

Answer (score 1):

If your app crashes with message "Unfortunately... stopped working", then do not press OK to eliminate the message, let it be on the screen. Now , check the [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) in android studio , and it will be displaying the cause of error. (Which type of error in which file and on which method). That should help you find the reason for the crash.

Comment: If you mean to say is that I'll look for the logcat the moment the error occur. Sad to say I won't be able to see anything on the logcat because I only send the apk to a friend for them to try. But this is what I'm seeing whenever I install the apk using the adb I'll show it on my post